# Iterating through array in Chart.js data field

Tags: javascript, chart.js

### Update:

```
var voltagedata1 = [];
    batterybank1.forEach(function(element){
        var voltage = {x: element.timestamp, y:element.voltage};
        voltagedata1.push(voltage);
})
```

```
data: voltagedata1
```

---

I have an array which I want to iterate through in the data field of the Chart.js chart.

This code works for example:

```
data: [
    {x: '2019-08-12 09:40:15', y:4}, {x: '2019-08-13 09:40:15', y:5}, {x: '2019-08-14 09:40:15', y:6},
],
```

Then trying to iterate through the array as follows:

```
batterybank1.forEach(function(element){
    console.log(element)
    "{x:\'element.timestamp', y:element.voltage},"
})
```

The console.log(element) gives a correct output, however the chart is not getting updated... on the console I am getting no warnings/errors - just the graph does not output.

The following does not work either, only the console.log is outputted but the graph is not updated.

```
batterybank1.forEach(function(element){
    console.log(element)
    "{x:\'2019-08-12 09:40:15', 1},"
})
```

Comment: why do you have those strings after console.log?

Comment: @MattEllen, the data field accepts data in the format as {x: , y: }, {x: , y: }, ... as far as I know - so I was trying to output that using the for loop in the data field. Refer to the first code part where I gave an example that works.

Comment: OK. Putting a string there will not output it to the console, or return it from a function. It will do nothing. How do you add data to a chart with chart.js?

Comment: I do not want that string to output to the console. Refer to my first example to see how data is added to chart.js - which is what I wanted to replicate then in the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's explained in [the documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html), that you add your points to the chart one at a time, like so:

```
batterybank1.forEach(function(element){
       chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(element);
})
```

This is assuming that `element` is in the same format as the points in `data`.

After that you need to call `chart.update();` to show the new data.

below is a working example:

```js
let data = [{t: '2019-08-12 09:40:15', y:4}, {t: '2019-08-13 09:40:15', y:5}, {t: '2019-08-14 09:40:15', y:6}, {t: '2019-08-15 09:40:15', y:7}];

var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('cht'), { type:'bar', data:
{
  datasets:[{
 label: 'CHRT - Chart.js Corporation',
 backgroundColor: '#ff0000',
  borderColor: '#ff0000',
  type: 'bar',
 pointRadius: 0,
 fill: false,
 lineTension: 0,
 borderWidth: 2,
  data: data}]
}, options:{
        scales: {
            xAxes: [
            {
              type: 'time',
        distribution: 'series',
        ticks: 
              {
         source: 'data',
         autoSkip: true
        }
            }]
        }
    } });
    
document.getElementById('addPoints').addEventListener('click', function() {
      let extra = [{t: '2019-08-16 09:40:15', y:4}, {t: '2019-08-17 09:40:15', y:5}, {t: '2019-08-18 09:40:15', y:6}, {t: '2019-08-19 09:40:15', y:7}];
      extra.forEach(p =>
      {
        chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(p);
      });
      
      chart.update();
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

<button id="addPoints">Add Points</button>

<canvas id="cht" class="chartjs" width="770" height="385" style="display: block; width: 770px; height: 385px;">
```

Comment: Thank you for that!
I adopted a similar method - check update in original post.